# Price variation Analysis, identify group of product category which has continuously increase/decrease in price

Tags: python, excel

**I need help on how to calculate this task using Excel pivot table and Python both?**

[image]

Basically, I'm trying to do a price variation analysis on the given data. for that, I want

> 1. which product category has continuously increased or decreased in price (within the year and overall)

> 2. want a single unit of the velocity measurement (it may be %) of increment or decrement in price (within the year and overall). eg. product category A has continuously increased in the year 2020 and Product category B has continuously decreased in the year 2021. but A has low velocity compared to B because the price difference between two transactions is high in product category B. **consider date-wise ascending in order to take the difference of price between two transactions.**

**I have Thousands of records with hundreds of such product categories. I want to automate this task.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def measure_change(df, year=None):
    df_ = df[df.date.dt.year == int(year)] if year is not None else df
    grouped = df_.sort_values(by='date').groupby(by='prod category')
    first, last = grouped.first().reset_index(), grouped.last().reset_index()
    change = pd.DataFrame({
        'category': first['prod category'],
        'change': (last.Price - first.Price) / last.Price
    })
    return change

print(measure_change(pd.read_excel('fname.xlsx')))
```

prints

| index | category | change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 0.2631578947368421 |
| 1 | b | 0.453781512605042 |
| 2 | c | 0.7226519337016575 |